# A dual notion to Lawvere-Tierney operators for geometric surjections?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, topos-theory

A geometric embedding into a Grothendieck topos can be characterised by giving the Lawvere-Tierney topology that induces it. This lets us reduce questions about subtoposes to more elementary order-theoretic questions about sublocales (of the subobject classifier).

What prevents us from applying the same analogy to geometric surjections? Is there a more elementary description of the collection of geometric surjections <del>into</del> out of a Grothendieck topos?

Starting from a discrete topos, i.e. a topos $\mathcal{E}$ of the form $Set^X$ for some set $X$, one can identify surjections out of $\mathcal{E}$ with exact comonads on $\mathcal{E}$ as one does in Richard Garner's ionads. But even ignoring the requirement of enough points for a moment, still the question remains, does the collection of such comonads have a more elementary order-theoretic description?

Comment: Do you really mean surjections **into** $\mathcal E$? Or surjections **out of** $\mathcal E$?

Comment: You're right. I should be asking about surjections out of $\mathcal{E}$. Even an ionad is a surjection out of $Set^X$.

Comment: I see. Well, by analogy with the "toy case" this must be essentially more difficult. Subsets of a set form a Boolean algebra, while the lattice of quotient sets is much more nasty. It is also very special in a sense, but not even modular (in most cases).

Comment: Another complication stems from the fact that while subtoposes of $\mathcal E$ are defined over $\mathcal E$, quotient toposes of $\mathcal E$ are defined "under $\mathcal E$", in a sense $\mathcal E$ "does not see them". 

Another related thing is that surjections are not necessarily quotients, so passing to the surjective image you not only "make $\mathcal E$ smaller" but also endow it with additional structure.

Comment: So, you are saying, since there is no device like a subobject classfier that classifies quotients, we cannot hope for an analogous result.

Comment: About your last sentence, that surjections are not necessarily quotients, are there a subset of geometric surjections that do just that? An intermediate step before full surjections and hopefully a three-way factorization system?

Comment: Well I don't want to go that far. It might be possible to do something, and it would be very interesting to do it. I am just trying to explain why is it essentially more complicated.

Comment: Btw although there is no quotient classifier, for each object $X$ one may construct the object of its quotients (it is isomorphic to the object of equivalence relations on $X$)

Comment: As for quotient geometric morphisms - there is some work done; they are related to exponentiable ones (Johnstone & Joyal, Niefield, Plewe). There are some relatively well understood subclasses, e. g. the so called triquotient maps.